# SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (421, b'4.7.0 Too many protocol errors (6) on this connection, closing transmission channel.')}?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtpclient

Getting this error  with smtplib with Office365. Any way out? Sending about  500 emails.

Comment: Don't make protocol errors..? or use a mail service.

Comment: What do you mean @thebjorn? I'm using smtp.office365.com with port 587.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not even half of what you need to know. Maybe it will help you ask a better question if you attach the debug log?(https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.set_debuglevel)